# Google Authenticator (Android) + Django says Invalid Token even after the Time Sync

Tags: django, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I am trying to implement Multi Factor Authentication using [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) and Google Authenticator. But every time I scan the QR Code, it says "Entered token is not valid."

After researching a lot, I've tried following things:

- I've tried downgrading Django version to 1.8
- Google Authenticator Time Correction for Codes (Says it's already synced).
- Changed server's timezone to IST (My local time zone).
- Tried the example app present in [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) (On my local system. Even that's not working!). Tough, their online example App is working (http://example-two-factor-auth.herokuapp.com/).

I am using django 1.9 and latest version of Google Authenticator (Android). I don't what could be the possible reason.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, although it works locally on my machine, it doesn't work once it's on staging server, weird. +1 on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with these steps:

1. In console `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov`
2. Change my settings.py to:

```python
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' 
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I hope to help.